# SQL Stored procedure to obtain top customers

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that goes through a "SALES" table and returns the best two customers of a pharmacy (the two customers who have spent more money).

Here's some code:

Table creation:

```
create table Customer (
    Id_customer int identity(1,1) Primary Key,
    Name varchar(30),
    Address varchar(30),
    DOB datetime,
    ID_number int not null check (ID_number > 0),
    Contributor int not null check (Contributor > 0),
    Customer_number int not null check (Customer_number > 0)
    )

create table Sale (
    Id_sale int identity(1,1) Primary Key,
    Id_customer int not null references Customer(Id_customer),
    Sale_date datetime,
    total_without_tax money,
    total_with_tax money
    )
```

Well, I don't know if this is useful but I have a function that returns the total amount spent by a customer as long as I provide the customer's ID.

Here it is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fGetTotalSpent]
(
    @Id_customer int
)
RETURNS money
AS
BEGIN
    declare @total money
    set @total = (select sum(total_with_tax) as 'Total Spent' from Sale where Id_customer=@Id_customer)
    return @total
END
```

Can someone help me get the two top customers?

Thanks
Chiapa

PS: Here's some data to insert so you can test it better:

```
insert into customer values ('Jack', 'Big street', '1975.02.01', 123456789, 123456789, 2234567891)
insert into customer values ('Jim', 'Little street', '1985.02.01', 223456789, 223456789, 2234567891)
insert into customer values ('John', 'Large street', '1977.02.01', 323456789, 323456789, 3234567891)
insert into customer values ('Jenny', 'Huge street', '1979.02.01', 423456789, 423456789, 4234567891)

insert into sale values (1, '2013.04.30', null, 20)
insert into sale values (2, '2013.05.22', null, 10)
insert into sale values (3, '2013.03.29', null, 30)
insert into sale values (1, '2013.05.19', null, 34)
insert into sale values (1, '2013.06.04', null, 21)
insert into sale values (2, '2013.06.01', null, 10)
insert into sale values (2, '2013.05.08', null, 26)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with a single query without any special functions:

```
select top 2 c.id_customer, c.name, sum(s.total_with_tax)
from customer c
join sale s on c.id_customer = s.id_customer
group by c.id_customer, c.name
order by sum(s.total_with_tax) desc
```

Comment: This will currently produce skewed results if multiple customers share the same name, as it will combine their sales.

Comment: Good catch.  I added the c.id_customer.  I was thinking about displaying "useful" end-user data and missed the id.

Comment: Martin's answer is probably better / more efficient, but in many cases simplicity has it's values.

This is more obvious to a less advanced user what's going on, and therefore will be easier to maintain and modify going forward.

Comment: Ordered by the sum to reduce cringing.

Answer (score 3):

This joins onto a CTE with the top customers.

Remove the `WITH TIES` option if you want exactly 2 and don't want to include customers tied with the same spend.

```
WITH Top2
     AS (SELECT TOP 2 WITH TIES Id_customer,
                                SUM(total_with_tax) AS total_with_tax
         FROM   Sale
         GROUP  BY Id_customer
         ORDER  BY SUM(total_with_tax) DESC)
SELECT *
FROM   Customer C
       JOIN Top2 T
         ON C.Id_customer = T.Id_customer
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really into SQL Server dialect, but this one will give you best customers in descending order along with money they spent:

```
select Id_customer, total_with_tax from
(select Id_customer, sum(total_with_tax) total_with_tax from Sale group by Id_customer)
order by total_with_tax desc
```

Comment: At least make SOME effort on the "highest 2" part... ?

Comment: @ErikE As I said, I don't have faintest idea about SQL Server dialect, that's why I didn't risk this.

Comment: All I know is that when I answer questions for DBMSes I'm less familiar with, I always try to learn something. And I try to present right/complete answers, or I don't bother answering at all.

Comment: Erike, calm down. The point here is trying to help people, more or less accurately, what counts is the intention. Imagine your lost and ask for directions: if some person says "I'm not sure how to get exactly there but if you follow north from here you will eventually find it" - this is a useful information, despite not being accurate or GPS level. Thanks for your participation